# PHP Multidimensional array number formatting returns A

Tags: php, arrays, tcpdf

I am having issue with number formatting of array elements. It always returns an "A" letter, no matter element value.

```
$tab = array_map(function ($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback( "/[0-9]+/", function ($matches) {
        return number_format($matches[0], 2, ',', ' ');
    }, $string);
}, $array);
```

I am calling for that value with adress `$tab['VII']['B']['podatek']['PTUG']`
An this is part of an Array:

```
$array = array(
        ...

        "VII" => array(
            ...
            "B" => array(
                ...
                "podatek" => array(
                    ...
                    "PTUG" => "789456123",
```

I am using tcpdf with this file as well, if that is making a trouble. What i need is to in proper fields call out for specific array elements and conver them to: 123 123,45 number format.

Also, would need to format date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy with addition of "r." after the date.

Comment: With the snippets you have shown, it is unclear with part of that array you are applying array_map to. Please provide a _proper_ [mre] of your issue, including sample data.

Comment: I am applying array_map for whole array, array itself is very long, posting whole here could make post hard to read. I provided all parts which are required.

Comment: Nobody said you should just dump your whole code, the link contains the word “minimal” for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_walk_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to run through your array. Within the callback, add your different checks to modify the values in each case.

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$val) {
    // Format integers
    if (filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
        $val = number_format($val, 2, ',', ' ');
    // Format dates
    } elseif (preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/', $val)) {
        $parts = explode('-', $val);
        $val = implode('-', array_reverse($parts));
    }
});
```

Comment: Works as I wanted to. Really appreciate that! Thank you.